# getModel return false after rewrite model

Tags: magento-1.9, product, overrides, catalog, model

I was trying to rewrite product model. It's my `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product>
                    My_Namespace_Model_Product
                </product>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
```

And `My_Namespace_Model_Product`

```
class My_Namespace_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{

public function test()
{
    var_dump(Mage::getModel('catalog/product'));
}
}
```

Why function `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` return me false after rewrite class?

Comment: Can you please post more specification here?

Comment: try to return some string in your `test()` method and call `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->test()` in another script

Comment: @RohanHapani . What you need?

Comment: @KeyurShah  method `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` return false, i cant call `test()`.

Comment: Please try to write `<product>My_Namespace_Model_Product</product>` on a single line (w/o linebreaks).

Comment: @sv3n Thank you, it works, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to write `<product>My_Namespace_Model_Product</product>` on a single line (w/o linebreaks).

Comment: I usually put it in one line, I never thought that the fact to put them in two lines causes problem @sv3n